# sqlite: convert values of type REAL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I try to access the sqlite database file of the Things App for Mac.
The table TMTask stores e.g. the creation date of a task in the column `creationDate` of type REAL. As I learned [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), I have to use date functions for casting between those julian days into human readable date values. But the following SQL statement did not results in what I expected:

`SELECT date(creationDate) FROM TMTask;`

Instead for all rows in that table `(null)` is returned. How can I select those dates from columns of type REAL ?

My main goal is to select all tasks created today by something like this:
`SELECT * FROM TMTask WHERE date(creationDate) = date('now');`

Comment: Can you post sample data of the table?

Comment: Please run `SELECT creationDate FROM TMTask LIMIT 5;` and post here

Comment: Are the dots really included in the column values?

Comment: Looks like unix timestamps, but with dots. F. e. `select date(datetime(1474149632,'unixepoch'))` returns '2016-09-17'

Comment: Unfortunately I can't include linebreaks here in a comment to format the SQL result. Therefor I post only one single result: `1.474.149.632`

Comment: `date(1315778432,'unixepoch')` - - > `2011-09-11`

Answer (score 1):

@LukStorms comment should be the accepted answer:
`select date(creationDate,'unixepoch') from TMTask;` did it.